# Populating Modal Form with User Selected Data in MVC Bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, model-view-controller, modal-dialog

I have been unsuccessfully trying to populate some elements in a Modal form using MVC and Bootstrap v3. The view consists of 2 multiselect dropdowns, a single select dropdown and a text area for displaying results.

I've been running into multiple issues but it all started with the fact that if  the user selects nothing from multiselect dropdowns then every option for them appears to get bound to the that model variable which is a list. I definitely don't want that by default as it sends a lot more stuff to the controller to ultimately be updated. If I could correct that behaviour I might not bother with the modal window at all tbh!

So after discovering that, I thought I would use a modal window to prompt the user with the selections they had made prior to submitting. This has turned out to be a lot more difficult than I anticipated, I cannot seem to get the javascript to populate the fields I have created in the modal window at all.

I've included code snippets for the view and model below, the controller is working fine its really just this issue of either preventing a select all by default binding to the model from multiselects or somehow passing all the relevant info to the modal window before doing the submit.

Any help is much appreciated, I've been round the houses with this, totally fed up with it tbh!

Thanks, 
N

Model

```
public StatusUpdaterVM()
        {
            //Get all the values for the drop downs
            Services = new List<String>(); e.g. GetInfo, SetInfo, DeleteParty
            Services.Sort();
            Domains = new List<String>(); e.g. Prod, Dev, Preprod
            Domains.Sort();
            resultsLst = new List<string>();
            resultsLst.Add("Awaiting selections...");
            Status = "DISABLED";
        }

        public List<string> Domains { get; set; }
        public List<string> Services { get; set; }
        public List<string> resultsLst { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
```

View

```
   @model FAKEPATH.Web.ViewModels.StatusUpdaterVM

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "StatusUpdater";
    }


@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "StatusUpdater", FormMethod.Post))
{                 
    <div class="container">
        <div class="well">
        <div class="row">     
            <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 text-left">
                <select id="multDomainSelect" multiple="multiple" name="Domains">
                    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Domains.Count(); i++)
                    {             
                        <option value="@Model.Domains[i]">@Model.Domains[i]</option>
                    }
                </select>
            </div>            
            <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 text-center">
                <select id="multServiceSelect" multiple="multiple" name="Services">
                    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Services.Count(); i++)
                    {             
                        <option value="@Model.Services[i]">@Model.Services[i]</option>
                    }
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 text-right">
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Status)
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="UpdStatus">Status</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                    </button>
                    <ul id='selStatusDD' class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a>DISABLED</a></li>
                        <li><a>PASS</a></li> 
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="well">
            <form>
                <label for="results">Results</label>
                <textarea class="form-control noresize" rows="25" id="results">
                    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.resultsLst.Count(); i++)
                    {             
                        @Model.resultsLst[i]               
                        @MvcHtmlString.Create("\n");                           
                    }
                </textarea>
            </form>
        </div> 
    </div>


    <!-- Modal Windows-->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Confirm action?</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">              
              You are about to update the following services in the specified Domains to a status of <strong>@Model.Status</strong>, do you wish to continue?
                <div class="row text-left top-buffer">   
                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                        &nbsp;
                    </div>    
                </div>
                <div class="row text-left top-buffer">                                           
                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                        <strong>Services</strong><br /><br />
                        <input type="hidden" name="hiddenServices" id="hiddenServices" value="" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                        <strong>Domains</strong><br /><br />
                        <input type="hidden" name="hiddenDomains" id="hiddenDomains" value="" />                            
                    </div>
                </div> 
            </div>

          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Cancel
            </button>
            <button type="submit" name="submitButton" class="btn btn-success">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-flash"></span> Execute
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row top-buffer">
        <div class="col-xs-12  text-center">
            <button type="button" id="execute" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" >
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-flash"></span> Update
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>                }


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#multDomainSelect').multiselect({
            enableFiltering: false,
            includeSelectAllOption: true,
            nonSelectedText: 'Select Domain',
            inheritClass: true,            
            onChange: function () {
                var selected = this.$select.val();
                var currTxt = document.getElementById('results').value;
                currTxt = currTxt.replace('Awaiting selections...', '');
                currTxt = currTxt.replace(currTxt, 'Domain(s) chosen: ' + selected + '\n');
                document.getElementById('results').value = currTxt;
            }
        });

        $('#multServiceSelect').multiselect({
            enableFiltering: true,
            includeSelectAllOption: true,
            nonSelectedText: 'Select Service',
            inheritClass: true,
            onChange: function () {
                var selected = this.$select.val();
                var currTxt = document.getElementById('results').value;
                currTxt = currTxt.replace('Awaiting selections...', '');
                currTxt = currTxt.replace(currTxt, 'Services(s) chosen: ' + selected + '\n');
                document.getElementById('results').value = currTxt;
            }
        });

        $('#selStatusDD a').click(function () {
            $('#UpdStatus').text($(this).text());
            document.getElementById('Status').value = $(this).text();
        });

        $("#execute").click(function () {
            var domains = document.getElementById('multDomainSelect').value;
            var services = document.getElementById('multServiceSelect').value;
            $(".modal-body #hiddenDomains").val(domains);
            $(".modal-body #hiddenServices").val(services);
            $("#myModal").modal({ show: true });
        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: You have a mistake here: `$(".modal-body #hiddenDomains").val()domains);`. Should be `$(".modal-body #hiddenDomains").val(domains);`.

Comment: And here: `$(".modal-body #Services").val(services);`. Should be `$(".modal-body #hiddenServices").val(services);`.

Comment: Thanks I have updated the code to correct now.

Comment: In the end I just used some Javascript to disable the execute button unless valid selections were made, so I didn't really solve the issue at hand but found a satisfactory alternative.